# R Markdown: Responsive image with link

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm working with R Markdown in a dashboard containing several tabs. In some of those tabs I want to display only an image with a link to a webpage. I managed to do this with this code:

````
---
title: "MyDashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
    logo: Logo.png
    favicon: Favicon.png
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

Row {data-height=350}
-------------------------------------

### THIS TAB CONTAINS NORMAL CONTENT

```{r}
plot(example)
```

Row {data-height=650}
-------------------------------------

### THIS TAB CONTAINS AN IMAGE WITH LINK

```{r}
```   

[<img src="image.png" style="width:100%; height=100%">](https://webpage.com/)
````

This displays the image with the link as expected, but when knitted, the image doesn't adjust to the tab's size and depending on the browser I use, vertical and horizontal scrollbars appear.

I would need to fit the image inside the limits of the tab in every browser I use, but all I tried until now failed.

Any help would be appreciated.